# usage of at24c02 eeprom with ethernet module

Tags: schematics, ethernet, microprocessor, mac, phy

ı design  [a altium circuit schematic](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-F5BHwIwpwKTzZaWHhadjhhaHM)  which consists of lan8720 tranciever rj45 and also [at24c02 eeprom](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0180.pdf) .However ı dont know exactly what MAC means and what it does. Why do we use eeprom with ethernet?

Comment: What do you know about Ethernet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All ethernet modules needs special mac adress to identify yourself and communicate with other devises .Therefore it is essential for you to use eeprom module for processor ethernet module  to have an identity

Answer (score 1):

A MAC address is a unique address every single Ethernet node has. It is a six byte address, the top three bytes of which are a manufacturer's unique ID and the bottom three bytes of which are a serial number. These number are used as source and destination addresses when sending Ethernet packets.

When you start to manufacture device with Ethernet ports you are supposed to register with the IEEE who will issue you with your manufacturer's ID which will not change. Then, as you manufacture devices, starting at 0, you will work your way up to 0xFFFFFF. You will usually see these numbers written as bytes separated by a colon. So, your first device would be MM:MM:MM:00:00:00 where MM:MM:MM is your three byte manufacturer's number. Your next would then be  MM:MM:MM:00:00:01 and so on.

If you manufacture HUGE numbers of devices you'll eventually run out and need to buy a new manufacturer's ID.

Now, you need to store this MAC address in your product, so a little EEPROM with a few bytes of data is ideal for this.

Comment: will ı directly connect SDA pin of the at24c16 module to the processor or ethernet module?

Comment: To the micro. This Microchip device is the PHY. :) You'll read the address from the EEPROM then send it to the MAC, all using your software running on (in your case)  the ARM.

Comment: how can ı make  ethernet socket programming in nxp lpc43s50 processor?

Comment: Are you talking about TCP sockets or physical sockets?

Comment: ı am talking about this schematic ,when I connect my  ethernet module to my processor , ı will need to program my socket

Comment: Sorry, I just don't know what you mean by "program my socket." Would you try and explain in a different way please?

Comment: yes of course .When ı connect my lan8710 driver to my microprocessor ,ı will need to program my processor pins.However it is very new consept for me to understand .Therefore ı ask how ı can do that .I dont know physical or TCP sockets .What  ı ask  is how it can be possible to program my pins for the ethernet .You can see my ethernet pins by looking at the pdf schematic.

Comment: If you mean how do I get software in to the processor, then it using the JTAG or SWD interface.  http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0480c/Chddgbee.html   There are loads and loads of good resources on this. Google ARM JTAG and read lots :)

Comment: Which ethernet code do you suggest for me to use? ı found alot of code .But ı cannot decide which one is better for my processor

Comment: Well, I can only give you my personal recommendation based on my general philosophy. Wouldn't mean it is the "right" or only answer. I would always go for FreeRTOS for a job like this, but this site doesn't like questions like that. Other people would recommend other ways of doing it and they'd be equally as valid.

Comment: ı am really thankful to you. You are very helpful .I wish you a good fortune in your life.

Comment: You are most welcome! :)